# Perl cgi updating a value in two different files

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a question about perl. There's a value in a file let say file.cgi and the value is:

```
red = 1;
```

There's another file name file2.cgi which have the value:

```
red = 2;
```

How to substitute the values between these two files? Which means that the value in file.cgi will be updated into 2 either. Can anyone help me?

Comment: i meant that file2.cgi is like a form. it passes the value to file.cgi who had an initial value of 1 and update the new value 2 into the file.cgi value from 1 to 2.

Comment: I started to correct your English and the markup in your question, but realised that you don't use a capital letter *anywhere*. Please be courteous and put a little effort into your question.

Comment: I am so sorry about that sir. But can anybody help me with this? Its kind of urgent.

Comment: You haven't explained the problem well enough for anyone to help you. If it's urgent then you shouldn't be looking for a free solution.

Comment: Its not like i want it now sir. I just need if somebody can help me with these problem. Thats all. Im not looking for free solution. Just needed some help. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: We're not blaming you for asking a question here. You should just offer a little more information about the problem. I do not understand your question, and that is not a language problem. In fact, I have no idea what the problem is. These values you are showing are not even variables because they have no sigil (`$`). Please take a moment to [edit] your question and to make yourself more clear. We do not care why or how quickly you need this fixed. Try to explain what the problem is, and you will get help. Also read [ask] if you are unsure how to use Stack Overflow.

Comment: Waiting for a explanation of the actual problem...

Comment: I had already post an improved version of this question. I hope that anybody can help me solve this problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003079/perl-updating-a-value-in-conf-file-from-a-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use CGI.pm param method to fetch the value from POST or GET parameters.

http://ods.com.ua/win/eng/program/Perl5Unleashed/ch22.phtml

In your form you should do something like this:

in $file2.cgi:

```
#print other stuff like header first
print <<EOS;
<form action="file.cgi">
  <input type="hidden" name ="red" value="$red">
  #other form elements
  <INPUT TYPE="Submit" VALUE="Do">
</form>
EOS
```

in file.cgi

```
my $q = CGI->new; 
my $red = $query->param('red');
print $q->header, # create the HTTP header
      $q->start_html('hello world'), # start the HTML
      $q->h2("\nCurrent \$red: $red\n"), # level 1 header
      $q->end_html; # end the HTML
```

Comment: thanks. i will try this solution first. thank you very much. i hope it can solve my problem. :)