# Perl updating a value in .conf file from a form

Tags: perl, parsing, cgi, updating

I have a admin.conf file and the file looks like this. For example,

```
[online_offline_status]
online_offline_status.online_offline_state = ONLINE
```

i have another file called index.cgi that works as a form. For example,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#index.cgi

require 'foobar-lib.pl';


ui_print_header(undef, $module_info{'desc'}, "", undef, 1, 1);


ui_print_footer("/", $text{'index'});

print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
print qq~
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cstyle17.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<div id="bar">
<span><p>Controller Settings</p></span>
</div>
<div id="tab-container">
<ul>
<li class="active"><span><a href="index.cgi">Offline / Online Status</a></span></li>
<li><span><a href="#">Data Online</a></span></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="main-container">
<table width='100%' height='60%'>
<tr>
<td width="50%" align="left">
<div id="title"><span>Offline / Online Status :</span></div>
</td>
<td>
<div id="form">
<form method="POST" action="index9.cgi">
<input type="radio" name="state" value="online">Online
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="state" value="offline">Offline
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan='2'>
<div id="button">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>

~;
```

When the user choose one of the radio option button and submit. The value will be sent to index9.cgi. It will process the form in this file (index9.cgi)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#index.cgi

require 'foobar-lib.pl';


ui_print_header(undef, $module_info{'desc'}, "", undef, 1, 1);


ui_print_footer("/", $text{'index'});

local ($buffer, @pairs, $pair, $name, $value, %FORM);
# Read in text
$ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/;
if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "POST")
{
read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
}else {
$buffer = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
}
# Split information into name/value pairs
@pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);
foreach $pair (@pairs)
{
($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
$value =~ tr/+/ /;
$value =~ s/%(..)/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
$FORM{$name} = $value;
}
$status = $FORM{state};

print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
print qq~
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cstyle17.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<div id="bar">
<span><p>Controller Settings</p></span>
</div>
<div id="tab-container">
<ul>
<li class="active"><span><a href="index.cgi">Offline / Online Status</a></span></li>
<li><span><a href="#">Data Online</a></span></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="main-container">
<table width='100%' height='60%'>
<tr>
<td width="50%" align="left">
<div id="title"><span>Offline / Online State :</span></div>
</td>
<td>
<div id="form">
<form method="link" action="index.cgi">
<p>Offline / Online state has been changed to : <b>$status</b><p>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan='2'>
<div id="button">
<input type="submit" value="Back">
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>

~;
```

Is it possible for when the user choose "offline" in index.cgi and sent to process the value ("offline") in index9.cgi, the value in the .conf file also be updated from ONLINE to OFFLINE?

Comment: I am still cant solve this problem. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Dirtiest way is to change the file on place via sed script, called from Perl..

Better way is to open the file in perl, read into a string, replace offline with online and print it out again, clobbering the old file.

ps: Did you hear about CGI.pm? It could ease your work.

Ps Ps: It would be better to use some modern web framework, like mojolicious, Dancer.

with CGI.pm

(be sure that the admin.conf is writeable by the webserver account)

In index9.cgi

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use Config::Tiny;
use Data::Dumper;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

my $q = CGI->new;
print $q->header();
my $state = $q->param('state');
my $file = "/full/path/to/admin.conf";
my $Config = Config::Tiny->read( $file );
my $status_in_file = $Config->{online_offline_status}->{online_offline_status.online_offline_state};

my $msg = "No changes being made";
$msg = "Status changed from $status_in_file to $status" if $status_in_file ne $status;
$Config->{online_offline_status}->{online_offline_status.online_offline_state} = $status;
$Config->write( $file );



print qq~
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cstyle17.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<div id="bar">
<span><p>Controller Settings</p></span>
</div>
<div id="tab-container">
<ul>
<li class="active"><span><a href="index.cgi">Offline / Online Status</a></span></li>
<li><span><a href="#">Data Online</a></span></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="main-container">
<table width='100%' height='60%'>
<tr>
<td width="50%" align="left">
<div id="title"><span>Offline / Online State :</span></div>
</td>
<td>
<div id="form">
<form method="link" action="index.cgi">
<p>$msg</p>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan='2'>
<div id="button">
<input type="submit" value="Back">
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>

~;
```

Comment: Can you teach me how to do it? I'm new with perl actually and not really understand this language. I just learned the language by my self in this three weeks.

Comment: I still cant figure this out.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! i hope i can make it work from your help. Thanks again. :D

Comment: Hello. I'm getting errors when i tried to execute the codes. It shows
Global symbol "$buffer" requires explicit package name at index9.cgi line 19 and many more.
What does this means?

Comment: I got the outcome of this code. But it is not what i wanted. The outcome is
"[offline_online_status]
offline_online_status.offline_online_state=ONLINE
offline_online_statusoffline_online_state=OFFLINE"
. If you can see, it adds another value to the .conf file and the dot is missing. How to make only the value is replace from "ONLINE" to "OFFLINE"

Comment: And also i noticed that it doesn't read the $status_in_file line. :(

Comment: Ok. i just also noticed that it does not read the dot symbol "." in offline_online_status.offline_online_state . If it can read the dot symbol then all problems will be solved. But how to do this?