# Reading a dot symbol (.) in perl

Tags: perl, cgi, symbols

I have a .conf file which looks like this:

```
[offline_online_status]
offline_online_status.offline_online_state=ONLINE
```

How can perl read the dot symbol (.) in the value above? Can anybody teach me?

Comment: What do you mean by "read the dot symbol"?

Comment: @RedCricket If you can see there is a dot between status and offline in that string. I want to take this string and write into another file but i just cant seem to retrieve the dot symbol as well. I will only get the "offline_online_statusoffline_online_state=ONLINE" without the dot symbol.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing special about the dot character from Perl's point of view.  Show some code, please.

Comment: @Sean You can see my codes in this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003079/perl-updating-a-value-in-conf-file-from-a-form

Comment: That's a lot of code to trawl through.  Reduce it to the smallest program that demonstrates the problem, and put it here, not there.

Comment: @batz So you want to write the `.` to a file, and more precisely you want to write `.offline_online_state=ONLINE` to a file, right?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can adapt this to what you need to do:

```
$ cat ./test.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

while(<DATA>) {
        next if /\[online_offline_status]/;
        my @arr = split /\./;
        print "." . $arr[1];
}

__DATA__
[online_offline_status]
online_offline_status.online_offline_state = ONLINE
$ ./test.pl
.online_offline_state = ONLINE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this, make your own modification:

```
use CGI;
use Config::Tiny;
use Data::Dumper;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

#location/directory of configuration file
my $file = "your configuration file path";
my $Config = Config::Tiny->read($file);

#reads the section, key and the value of the configuration file.
my $status_in_file = $Config->{"offline_online_status"}->{"offline_online_status.offline_online_state"};
```

And after that just print the $status_in_file. This code will read the entire key and value in your configuration file.