# Infinite loop reading a configuration file

Tags: perl, ubuntu

I have to set up my configuration file, for example admin.conf and I want my Perl program to read the configuration file and output the value in an infinite loop. When I change the value in the configuration file. The value in the program's output will update the into a new value. Can anybody show me an example on how to do this? I also use `IO::Socket::INET` as my Perl package. How to read the configuration file first then do an infinite loop?

Here is my admin.conf

```
[state]
status_state = ONLINE
```

Here is the output that I wish for

```
ONLINE
ONLINE
ONLINE
ONLINE
```

And when I change the value in my admin.conf. The value will be updated into this:

```
OFFLINE
OFFLINE
OFFLINE
OFFLINE
```

I'm using **terminal Ubuntu** to output my value.

Answer (score 1):

To read that configuration file, you have to use the Config::Tiny package. You can learn to read that configuration file from here ( [Reading a dot symbol (.) in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058298/reading-a-dot-symbol-in-perl/22656369#22656369))

To solve your problem, please use this code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use IO::Socket::INET;
use CGI;
use Config::Tiny;
use Data::Dumper;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

$| = 1;


while (1) {

# Write some data to the client
my $file = "The path of your configuration file";

my $Config = Config::Tiny->read($file);
#reads the section, key and the value of the configuration file.
my $status = $Config->{"state"}->{"status_state"};

    sleep 2;
    
    print "$status\n";

}
```